# In C strtok() is working for "," (commas) but not for spaces " ". Getting a seg fault when working with spaces

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm new here. This is my first post!
So I wrote code in C to take in a comma separated text file and read it into a 2D array. I used strtok() for that. It worked. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *data = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open 11.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char table[20][20][3];
    char buffer[60];

    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(data, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (char *s = strtok(buffer, ","); s != NULL; s = strtok(NULL, ","))
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < strlen(s) + 1; k++)
            {
                table[i][j][k] = s[k];
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", table[19][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The data I'm trying to read into the 2D array looks like:

```
08,02,22,97
49,49,99,40
81,49,31,73
52,70,95,23
```

It is a 20x20 matrix with numbers separated by commas.
The above program works fine (I'm printing out an element of this 2D array to check if the program is working). But when the numbers are separated by spaces:

```
08 02 22 97 
49 49 99 40 
81 49 31 73 
52 70 95 23
```

and when I replace the "," with " " in the strtok() function I get a seg fault. I'm at a loss for why this is the case.
Thank you for the help!

**EDIT:**
**The bug has been fixed!**
@Vlad From Moscow very correctly pointed out that fcanf() is not the correct function to use to read into a buffer a string with white space. He suggested instead to use fgets() which can read white space. I was still facing a seg fault because the first token returned by strtok() was a pointer to NULL. I'm not sure why its doing that because when I fed strtok() an array with the same string without using fgets() in a while loop as shown, there were no issues:

```
char str[] = "08 02 22 97";
```

So to fix this I put a condition in the for loop to skip to the next iteration if the strtok() returned a NULL pointer.
The second issue was that my buffer wasn't large enough (spaces are 4 bytes compared to 1 byte for a char). Fixing these two issues I got the code to work!

Below is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *data = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open 11.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char table[20][20][3];
    char buffer[61];

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), data) != NULL)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (char *s = strtok(buffer, " "); s != NULL; s = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            if (s == NULL)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < strlen(s) + 1; k++)
                {
                    table[i][j][k] = s[k];
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%i\n", atoi(table[19][19]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated: the first line in the first example ends with `<COMMA>97<ENTER>` ... the first line in the 2nd example ends with `<SPACE>97<SPACE><ENTER>`

Comment: @pmg I think i did that accidentally when sticking those numbers in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `fscanf` with the format specifier `%s` reads data until a white space character is encountered. So you can not use the function `fscanf` as you are using it in the while statement

```
while (fscanf(data, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
```

to read strings containing embedded white spaces.

Instead use the standard C function `fgets`.

Pay attention to that instead of this for loop

```
for (int k = 0; k < strlen(s) + 1; k++)
{
    table[i][j][k] = s[k];
}
```

you could use the standard string function `strcpy` as for example

```
strcpy( table[i][j], s );
```

Also this call

```
printf("%s\n", table[20][0]);
```

invokes undefined behavior because for an array declared like

```
char table[20][20][3];
```

the valid range of the first index is ]0, 20 ). That is you may not use the value 20 as the index.

Comment: I'm using fgets() in a while loop as `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), data))` I'm still getting a seg fault. Even though the first row is correctly being stored in the buffer. But the first token being returned by strtok() is nothing, which I cannot figure out why. Strlen() being called on a NULL pointer is responsible for the seg fault. Any ideas?

Comment: @ArjunSingh Use the separator " \n" that contains two characters, space and the new linec character, in the call of strtok.

Comment: I corrected the array index. That was a typo on my part. Sorry. But I'm still getting a seg fault using " /n" as the delimiter in strtok(). I removed the while loop and tried feeding strtok() the first row of the data as an array of the form `char str[] = "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";` with " " as the delimiter and the code worked just fine. I think the issue is with how fgets() is passing the first row of the data into the buffer. But i can't figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @ArjunSingh I advice to close the question selecting the best answer and ask a new question with your updated code.

Comment: I've figured out the bug. I updated my original question with the solution and the updated code. Thank you so much for your guidance. It was key to fixing the bug. Thanks!